# Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to generates the variable Fourier series for a square wave signal and a uniformly distributed noise signal.

This is my code and I have this error

Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'.

```
fs = 1000;       %Sampling  frequency Hz [1 1000]
l = 1 ;         %Signal length sec [1 10]

% Fourier Series Parameter
h = 1;    %Amplitude [0 10]; default 1
k =1 ;  %Fourier Series lenght(k);[1 21]

% Noise Signal specific parameters

h1 = 1;  %Amplitude (h); [0 10]; default: 1

%calculate signal
%x = 0:1/fs:L-1/fs; 

x = 0:1/fs:l-1; 

n = [1; Inf];
f(x) = 4*h/pi * symsum( (1./k) * sin((2*pi*k*x)),k,2*n-1,n); %Fourier series for a square wave signal

%uniformly distributed noise signaL
%Noise signal specific parameters
%Amplitude (h); [0 10]; default: 1
h2 = 1 ; % Noise Amplitude

sig_Noise = h2*(f(x) + sigma*randn(1,length(x))); %  signal with phase  & amplitude noise 

plot(x,f(x))
```

my summation is here [Summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opAm6.png)
how can I fix it?

Comment: k is of type syms? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html?s_tid=doc_ta

Comment: yes  , The summation of k from 2n-1 to n .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
fs = 1000; %Sampling Frequency Hz [1 1000]
l = 10; % Signal Length sec [1 10]
h = 1; % Amplitude [0 10] - Default 1
h2 = 1; % Noise Amplitude
sigma = 1;
x = 0:(1/fs):(l-1);

syms k;
syms f(x);
f(x) = 4*h/pi() * symsum((1/k)*sin(2*pi()*k*x),k,1,Inf); % Fourier series for a square wave signal

fplot(x,f(x));
```

Actually, if you want to work with symbolic maths... you have to work with symbolic variables that can be declared using the `syms` keyword. For plotting, the `fplot` function must be used instead of `plot`.